# Dynamic GUI problem

Tags: dynamic, piecewise

I'm fairly new to Mathematica and currently making a simple GUI.

I'd like to work with dropdown menus and I'd like to dynamically change the possibilites of those menus depending on what's selected in the previous menu.

Using a ton of If-functions seemed impractical to me and so I ended up using the Piecewise-function instead (which might be stupid as well).

```
   (*Dynamische Eingabefeld-Abhängigkeiten*)
Dynamic[Piecewise[{{forminput={"Viereck","Kreis"},method=="2D"},{forminput={"Quader", "Zyllinder"},method=="3D"}}]]
Dynamic[Piecewise[{
    {diminput=Column[{"Länge: "InputField[Dynamic[l],Number], "Breite: "InputField[Dynamic[b],Number]}], form=="Viereck"},
    {diminput=Column[{"Radius: "InputField[Dynamic[r],Number]}], form=="Kreis"},
    {diminput=Column[{"Länge: "InputField[Dynamic[l],Number], "Breite: "InputField[Dynamic[b],Number], "Höhe: "InputField[Dynamic[h],Number]}], form=="Quader"},
    {diminput=Column[{"Radius: "InputField[Dynamic[r],Number], "Höhe: "InputField[Dynamic[h],Number]}], form=="Zyllinder"}
    }]]

(*GUI Input-Oberfläche*)
Panel[
Grid[{
    {Style["2D oder 3D mesh?", Bold]},
    {PopupMenu[Dynamic[method],{"2D","3D"}]},
    {Style["Geometrische Form:", Bold], Style["Dimensionen [mm] :", Bold]},
    {Dynamic[PopupMenu[Dynamic[form],forminput]], Dynamic[diminput]} 
}]]
```

The code works as intended, however I cannot put a ";" behind the Piecewise-Functions. Once I do that it stops working. At the same time, having the evaluation of those functions permanently shown kinda ruins the look.

My questions would be:

1) is there a smarter way to hoave dependent drop down menus?

2) is there a way to surpress the output of the Piecewise-Functions without having them to stop working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0) `Piecewise` is more for math applications. I'd use `Switch` as more readable here: `Switch[method, "2D", {"Viereck", "Kreis"}, "3D", {"Quader", "Zyllinder"}]` etc.

2) Correct, with your approach you need to keep first two `Dynamic` visible. See `Dynamic` and tutorials linked at the bottom of its documentation. Other ways to react to changes of certain variable is to use `DynamicWrapper` or the second argument of `Dynamic`

```
DynamicWrapper[ controller[Dynamic[var]], var2 = something[var], TrackedSymbols :> {var}]

(*or*)


controller[Dynamic[var, {Automatic, (var2 = something[var])&}]]
```

See docs for more details.

1) Here is my implementation, and I don't really use any of methods mentioned above. I just make `form` menu dynamic based on `method` value instead of having an additional `forminput` variable.

```
DynamicModule[{method = "2D", forms, form = "Viereck", dims, l, b, r, 
  h},
 Panel[
  Grid[{
    {Style["2D oder 3D mesh?", Bold]},
    {PopupMenu[Dynamic[method], {"2D", "3D"}]},
    {Style["Geometrische Form:", Bold], Style["Dimensionen [mm] :", Bold]},
    {Dynamic[PopupMenu[Dynamic[form], forms[method]]], 
     Dynamic[Grid[dims[form], Alignment -> {Left, Center}]]}
    }]
  ],
 Initialization :> (
   forms[method_] := 
    Switch[method, "2D", {"Viereck", "Kreis"}, 
     "3D", {"Quader", "Zyllinder"}];

   dims[form_] := Switch[form,
     "Viereck", {{"Länge:", 
       InputField[Dynamic[l], Number]}, {"Breite:", 
       InputField[Dynamic[b], Number]}},
     "Kreis", {{"Radius:", InputField[Dynamic[r], Number]}},
     "Quader", {{"Länge:", 
       InputField[Dynamic[l], Number]}, {"Breite:", 
       InputField[Dynamic[b], Number]}, {"Höhe:", 
       InputField[Dynamic[h], Number]}},
     "Zyllinder", {{"Radius:", 
       InputField[Dynamic[r], Number]}, {"Höhe:", 
       InputField[Dynamic[h], Number]}}
     ]
   )
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using Switch and assigned the strings to values. for example: PopupMenu[Dynamic[method],{0->Spacer[0],1->"2D",2->"3D"}]. Really like how you made seperate functions for that, which makes "designing" the Grid look much more structured. Still have to wrap my head around what DynamicModule does though!

Comment: @p4di here it is mostly for localization of those symbols and also for storing definitions of `forms` and `dims` so you can deploy it as cdf and it will work.